# "Unreleased Resource: Database" forify issue

Tags: java, fortify

I have scanned my project using fortify tool, in the generated fortify report I got `Unreleased Resource: Database` issue in the following method.

```
public String handleInput( HttpServletRequest request, HtmlGenerator htmlGenObj ) {

    HashMap old_child_list  = new HashMap();
    HashMap old_parent_list = new HashMap();
    HashMap new_child_list  = new HashMap();
    HashMap new_parent_list = new HashMap();

    logger.debug( "Start of handle Input" );
    String dataSource     = request.getParameter( "datasource" ) == null ? "" : request.getParameter( "datasource" );
    String sortBy         = request.getParameter( "sortby" ) == null ? "" : request.getParameter( "sortby" );
    long sqlConsStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //
    // Get the sql query based on data source
    //
    String sqlQuery       = this.getSql( dataSource, request );

    // If any error then return
    if( sqlQuery.startsWith( "ERROR" ) ) {
        return sqlQuery;
    }

    if( sortBy.trim().length() > 0 ) {
        logger.debug( "Sort by value = " + sortBy );
        int orderByIndex = sqlQuery.indexOf( "order by" );

        // If order by already exists then remove that value.
        if( orderByIndex > 0 ) {
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery.substring( 0, orderByIndex );
        }

        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " order by " + sortBy;
    }

    plog.debug( getUniqueId( request ) + "SQL Construction Time = " + ( ( System.currentTimeMillis()- sqlConsStartTime )/1000.0 ) );

    logger.info( "Final SQL = " + sqlQuery );

    String results  = "NONE";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx  = ( Context ) initCtx.lookup( "java:comp/env" );
        // Look up for the data source
        DataSource ds   = ( DataSource ) envCtx.lookup( "NavigatorCon" );
        conn            = ds.getConnection();
        htmlGenObj.setSql( sqlQuery );

        if( dataSource.equals( "compass" ) ) {
            results          = doCompassSearch( sqlQuery, conn, request, old_parent_list, old_child_list );
            String matchType = request.getParameter( "coname_st" ) == null ? "" : request.getParameter( "coname_st" );

            if( "fuzzy".equals( matchType ) ) {

                long rollupSqlConsStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                String rollupSql = build_rollup_sql( conn, old_parent_list, old_child_list, new_parent_list, new_child_list );   //System.out.println( "Rollup SQL: " + rollupSql );

                plog.debug(getUniqueId(request)+"Rollup SQL Construction Time = "+ ((System.currentTimeMillis()- rollupSqlConsStartTime)/1000.0) );

                if( rollupSql.length() > 0 ) {
                    String rollupResult = doCompassSearch( rollupSql, conn, request, old_parent_list, old_child_list );
                    results             = results + rollupResult;
                    // Build the new sql which returns both parent and child records.This is used in Excel download
                    sqlQuery            = sqlQuery + " UNION " + rollupSql;
                }  //System.out.println( "Navigator Query is: \n" + sqlQuery + "\n" );

                htmlGenObj.setSql( sqlQuery );
            }
        }

        else if( dataSource.equals( "psar" ) ) {
            results = getAMSearchResults( sqlQuery, conn, request, htmlGenObj );
        }

        else if( dataSource.equals( "knac" ) ) {
            results = do_knac_search( sqlQuery, conn, request );
        }

        else if( dataSource.equals( "auth_user" ) ) {
            results = do_auth_user_search( sqlQuery, conn, request );
        }

        else if( "docstore".equalsIgnoreCase( dataSource ) ) {
            results = this.doDocStoreSearch( sqlQuery, conn, request );
        }

    }

    catch( Exception sqle ) {
        logger.fatal( "Error : " + sqle.toString(), sqle );
    }

    finally {
        try {

            conn.close();
        }

        catch( Exception e ) {
            // giveup
        }
    }

    old_child_list.clear();
    old_parent_list.clear();
    new_child_list.clear();
    new_parent_list.clear();

    logger.debug( "End of handle Input");
    return results;
       }
```

As per my knowledge this issue will come if the connection is not closed properly, but in this connection is closed inside finally block.

Can any one suggest me how to resolve it? xxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

A NullPointerException maybe thrown, hence maybe change the second Exception into `Throwable` as NullPointerException is derived from the checked Exception class. *Maybe the code analysis had a problem here.*

And then, since Java 7 you can use try-with-resources to automatically close things:

```
try (Connection con = getDbConnection()) {
```

without `finally`. Also holds for the PreparedStatement and ResultSet.

As you named quality: it is deemed better style to use `SQLException e`, or something like `SQLException | NullPointerException e`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the `ResultSet rs` and the `PreparedStatement ps`. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggessions, i will try.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO04-J.+Release+resources+when+they+are+no+longer+needed see "Compliant Solution (Java SE 7: try-with-resources)"

Comment: Hi fiffy that issue is fixed, same issue is araised in the above file. can u give me solution??

Comment: I dont think that this is the same issue. Consider the comments of DavidC regarding SQL injection, this is a serious security issue.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of fortify and security I would pay more attention o your SQL Injection...

```
 String sortBy         = request.getParameter...

[...]
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " order by " + sortBy;
```

In general Fortify can generate a huge number of false positive results.

Comment: i am not getting you. what changes i need to do with sqlQuery

Comment: do not concatenate user input in SQL queries. Use a level of indirection, interpolaiton, sanitizing/encoding or validation at least.